# Get value of last row and column in sqlLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I want to get the last value example

```
ID NAME SURNAME
1  Mark X
2  Alex Z
```

I want to get the value where surname equals Z, or the last value inserted y have this code

DB CLASS

```
 public Cursor getData(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME,null);

   //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);




    return cursor;



}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
 void getDatas(){
   Cursor c =  helper.getData();
    if (c.getCount()==0){

        return;

    }

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()){
            buffer.append(c.getString(2));

    }

    TEXT=buffer.toString();

}
```

With that i am getting example= XZ instead of only Z

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (case when surname = 'Z' then 1 else 2 end),
         id desc
limit 1;
```